# Know if an ActiveMQConnection using failover is connected or not to a broker

Tags: java, activemq-classic

In my Java application I am using the failover transport to connect to a local ActiveMQ broker:

```
failover:(tcp://0.0.0.0:61616)
```

I create one single connection that I reuse in the rest of the application:

```java
ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
```

In another part of the application when I receive some external call I need to send a message to the broker, and so, for doing that I create a new "Session":

```java
Session locSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

When the broker is down my app tries to reconnect to the broker forever (this is the expected behavior I really want to have).
However, the problem is that if the broker is down and I receive a call that invokes the code that executes the `connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)` then my app hangs forever on this line of code waiting for the app to reconnect successfully to the broker and then create the session.

Please, do you know any way to check before I execute `createSession` if the `connection` object is trying  to reconnect or it is really connected? If I am able to know this I could avoid the creation of the session if the app is not connected to the broker (only trying to reconnect) and therefore I would avoid to hanging on `connection.createSession` forever (I would raise an exception).

I wasn't able to find any property or method on `ActiveMQConnection` to gather this information.

Answer (score 0):

The failover: url provides a setting [startupMaxReconnectAttempts](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) to prevent infinite retry when connecting to the broker the *first* time.

Also note-- If you want an exception to bubble up, that conflicts with requirement to have infinite retry. You would need to adjust the failover settings to match your intended behavior, by setting a max count or max time to perform retry, then throw an exception and unblock your caller.

For example, you could indicate you only want to retry for 5 minutes, then receive an exception to handle in the code to prevent the infinite blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and suggestions. They helped me a lot in re-focusing the problem.
However I f found the answer to my question using the method "getTransport().isConnected()".

Comment: It's worth noting that using this ActiveMQ-specific method will make your application non-portable (i.e. you won't be able to change to a different JMS broker) and is therefore generally discouraged. Also this check is inherently race prone. In other words `isConnected()` may return `true` when you call it, but by the time you invoke `createSession` the connection might have failed. In other words, it's not a particularly reliable way to avoid your problem.